# Multiple stream_filters /me Facebook graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm attempting to do some complex Facebook graph queries. I want to retrieve a user's timeline only from specific apps. Here's what I have:

[https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=home.filter(app_2915120374).limit(20).fields(...)&access_token=](https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=home.filter%28app_2915120374%29.limit%2820%29.fields%28...%29&access_token=)...

So that works great, however, what if I want to do multiple apps? Providing multiple filters inside `.filter()` outputs an error.

[https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=home.filter(app_2915120374,app_2305272732).limit(20).fields(...)&access_token=](https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=home.filter%28app_2915120374,app_2305272732%29.limit%2820%29.fields%28...%29&access_token=)...

```
{
    error: {
        message: "(#606) Invalid filter_key app_2915120374,app_2305272732",
        type: "OAuthException",
        code: 606
    }
}
```

I'd rather not perform multiple requests, since that can take awhile. And, plus, it's not one unified feed. Ex: if I pull 20 statuses, then 20 photos, there will be some gaps in the timeline.

And NO, I don't want to use FQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested a little, and I assume that you can only pass one stream filter at once. This would also be consistent to the docs at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/home/ stating that

> Retrieve only posts that match **a particular stream filter**. Valid
>   filters to be used here can be retrieved using the FQL stream_filter
>   table.

Comment: Lame! I ended up using FB's batch API to perform requests for each filter.